# Does REDIS support event listeners?

Tags: java, callback, redis, listener, jedis

My USE Case:

I want to have a key in redis and want a callback to some method (Using Jedis Java client) when the keys value changes or exceeds some threshold. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Like this? https://redis.io/topics/notifications Basically it is: 1. Activate notifications, 2. subscribe to a special pub/sub channel, 3. setup up which keys shall trigger notification events - you then can process the notifications.

Comment: No that seems too generic , I want something like 'when key val exceeds X ' callback method Y . Triggring a call back for every change in value seems too resource intensive for what i require

Comment: Well, you'll have to work with the tools you got, right? But anyway, it was just the first google hit, I found. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: You could still use pub/sub if you make the setter of the key publish on your condition, only. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/QRMcMXBERxw > "MULTI
ZINCRBY square:123:456 1 foo
PUBLISH square:123:456 "foo is updated"
EXEC"

Comment: Or maybe this is for you? https://matt.sh/advanced-redis-pubsub-scripts

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

In a first redis-cli:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> psubscribe __key*
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
1) "psubscribe"
2) "__key*"
3) (integer) 1
```

Open another terminal with a second redis-cli

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> config set notify-keyspace-events KEg$
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> config get notify-keyspace-events
1) "notify-keyspace-events"
2) "g$KE"
127.0.0.1:6379> set foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> del foo
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

You should see in the redis-cli first terminal:

```
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:foo"
4) "set"
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*"
3) "__keyevent@0__:set"
4) "foo"
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*"
3) "__keyspace@0__:foo"
4) "del"
1) "pmessage"
2) "__key*"
3) "__keyevent@0__:del"
4) "foo"
```

Just be aware that this is not a free functionality and the performances are necessarily impacted because REDIS must trigger the PUBLISH command on each of the events.

See the documentation here: https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/